# Splitting file groups of large SQL Server database using FileStream

Tags: sql-server, backup, disaster-recovery

**Background:**

I have a SQL Server database which is storing documents in the file stream. These documents are usually accessed via Web API by Mobile Apps and Modern JS Apps.

The size of the database is around 2 TB with a growth rate of 30% per year.

**Situation:**

Full backup of the server happens every night to the disaster environment. This is taking a substantial time.

**Task:**

To reduce the backup load, we only want to back up the last year's documents in the disaster recovery environment because there are very fewer chances that documents older than one year have been changed.

**Action:**

To do so, I've created two filegroups, one for the current documents (storing document added no longer than one year ago) and one for the archive document (storing document older than one year). My plan was to store these two filegroups in a different drive and ignore the drive having old documents in the backup process.

**Result:**

This hasn't worked because if a filegroup is missing, SQL Server marked your database as unavailable or under maintenance.

**Question:**

Is there any other way of splitting the database without changing the existing schema or stored procedure etc.

Comment: have you tried piecemeal restore,[here](https://www.sqlshack.com/piecemeal-restore-in-sql-server-database/) you can find some info.